In IUPAC, should you consider priority list first or should you give the least number to the double bonds despite priority order in numbering chain?
This is a very basic question but I am little confused so I need others opinions. Consider the following organic compound below.

When naming this, would you give the least number to the double bond like this, giving the least number to the double bond.
So, the name here would be 4-hydroxyhex-2-en-1,6-dial or 4-hydroxy-2-hexen-1,6-dial, or,

Would you consider giving the -OH lowest number when numbering the chain. (I got this confusion because, in priority order, alcohols are higher than the double or triple bonds priority, but in order of nomenclature it says first find the longest chain containing the main functional group and then if it has double or triple bonds, number it in a way that those bonds get a least number and then if it doesn't have double or triple bonds, give the substituents the lowest number. This contradictions is what confuses me.)
So, would the compounds name be 3-hydroxyhex-4-en-1,6-dial or 3-hydroxy-4-hexen-1,6-dial


I think 4-hydroxyhex-2-en-1,6-dial or 4-hydroxy-2-hexen-1,6-dial would be correct IUPAC name here. Because in polyfunctional compounds, we have to find primary functional group and the rest will be treated as substituents while naming. And, since we have to prioritize double/triple bonds over substituents, the double/triple bonds will be assigned lower number than substituents ($\ce{-OH}$ here). Hope this clears your confusion.

Complementary hint to the OP: the resources page compiles freely accessible references about chemical nomenclature (including the Blue Book specific to organic chemistry).

Almost. The correct IUPAC name is (2E)-4-hydroxyhex-2-enedial.
